# Unable to load static images in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, image, react-native

My folder structure :

-assets

--images

---potrait.png

-src

--file.js

I want to load my image in file.js but it throws error

`<Image source={require('../assets/images/potrait.png')} />`

Error:

error: Error: Unable to resolve module ../assets/images/potrait.png from D:\munish\Desktop\Invictus\reach-app\src\reactNativeCamera.js:

None of these files exist:

- potrait.png
- assets\images\potrait.png\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, react disables imports outside of src. You should move them to inside the src or to the `public` folder where it can be accessed through `/` ( not recommended because it will replicate the image, should be avoided for the best optimization ).

Comment: Okay can you help me with an example because even if i put my image in src folder it gives same error.

Comment: Please check this example at expo (Note that this is the `src` folder) https://snack.expo.dev/ @MunishVira

Comment: i am dng the same thing only than why its is giving me error/

Comment: can u write the new file structure and how u r importing @MunishVira

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this syntax?

```
<Image source={{uri: localPath}}/>
```